# ListView só aparece quando clico para fechar o teclado

Tags: android, android-layout

Não sei como solucionar este problema, mas a list-View não aparece quando faço a busca, ela só vem há aparecer quando clico no botão para fechar o teclado, parece que quando aperto o botão ele atualiza a Activity e ai aparece muito estranho.

Segue abaixo imagens com o problema.

Att Cristiano.

[image: List_View não aparece]

[image: O list-view só aparece quando clico no botão para fechar o teclado]

Código

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="O que você está procurando?"
            android:textColor="#fb7b03"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtBusca"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/editstyle"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgprocurar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edtBusca"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/procurar" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnOrdenar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/editstyle"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtBusca"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Organizar por:"
            android:textColor="#fb7b03"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewProdutos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spnOrdenar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imglimpar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/canpesq" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fechar o teclado via código quando o search view terminar

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

Comment: Postei o código mas não está funcionando porque estou usando android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout... Acho que é isso pois tenho um menu que fica no canto superior esquerdo.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta, com um código que vc pode fechar o teclado virtual no sucesso da resposta do search

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo consegui com o seguinte código  ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtBusca.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Legal, deve ter outros modos de resolver, mas eu acredito que essa seja o mais simples e mais fácil mesmo